# Why Infinite for loop persists though terminating conditions are there?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This function is for creating a dynamic table out of two inputs type text values.

the second `for` infinity loops although there is a condition that `j` is less than the input value(`col`). i tried with values of [ `row = 5 columns = 5`] but still get infinite loop.

```
function addtable(){

    var row = document.getElementById('row1').value;
    var col = document.getElementById('col1').value;
    if( row === "" || col === ""){alert("Please Enter Row & Column values");}
    //console.log(row*col);
    table = document.createElement('table');
    //table.id='Ntables';
    console.log(table);
    var i = 0;

    for( i; i <(row+1) ; i++)
    {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        //tr.id='Ntablerows';
        console.log(tr);
        table.appendChild(tr);
        var j = 0;

        for(j; j < (col+1); j++)
        {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            console.log(td);
            tr.appendChild(td);
            //td.id='Ntablecols'
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'text';
            //input.id = 'Ntableinput';
            td.appendChild(input);
        }
     }
     return (0);
}
```

***Edit***: it was not an infinite loop, it was a number being concatenated to the loop variable. making it bigger than expected.

[image]

Comment: do you realise that your loops will create for example 4 rows of 5 columns, if rows is 3, and columns is 4? what I see in the middle of that wall of `td` is a `tr` ... so, there seems to be a finite number of `td` between `tr` - it's just that there's probable about 10 times as many as you expect `'4'+1` is `41` not `5`

Comment: Also the alert() wont stop the rest of the code to execute...

Comment: @facundo there is supposed to be a return there but i removed it, i thought i may be causing a problem.

Comment: simplest fix ... `var row = +document.getElementById('row1').value;
    var col = +document.getElementById('col1').value;`

Comment: so ... *there is no infinite loop*

Comment: @JaromandaX i counted them i tried 1 row 1 column table, i got 11 rows X 11 columns , if 2X2 i get 21 rows X 21 columns.
what is happening here?

Comment: I said *`'4'+1` is `41` not `5`* then I said *simplest fix ... `var row = +document.getElementById('row1').value; var col = +document.getElementById('col1').value;`* - the problem is an input value is a string ... a string + 1 is not the same as a number + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var row = document.getElementById('row1').value;
var col = document.getElementById('col1').value;
if( row === "" || col === ""){alert("Please Enter Row & Column values");}
row = parseInt( row )
col = parseInt( col )
```

Comment: it worked now it does not concatenate the +1 onto the variable. +1thanks